# calling php function that queries database can't use $con resource.

Tags: php

This query works fine when I call it in in my php page without surrounding it with a function and a name

```
//MAKE DATABASE CALL TO GET PRODUCT 
$product_id = $line_value['productId'];
$product_query = "SELECT * 
                  FROM products
                  WHERE id = '$product_id'
                  LIMIT 1";
$product_result = pg_query($con, $product_query);
while ($product_row = pg_fetch_assoc($product_result)){
    $product = $product_row['product'];
}
//works
echo $product;
```

But I get an error when I try to put it within a function

`$product =  _get_product($product_row['product']);`
`echo $product'`

```
function _get_product($product_id){

//prints 1
echo $product_id
    //MAKE DATABASE CALL TO GET PRODUCT 
    $product_id = $line_value['productId'];
    $product_query = "SELECT * 
                      FROM products
                      WHERE id = '$product_id'
                      LIMIT 1";
    $product_result = pg_query($con, $product_query);
    while ($product_row = pg_fetch_assoc($product_result)){
        $product = $product_row['product'];
    }

return $product;

}
```

> Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   /home/www.site.com/file.php on line
>   263

I thought perhaps that the function didn't have access to the included db connection file at the top of the page, but when I put that within the function, I got this error

> Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid
>   input syntax for integer: "" LINE 3: WHERE id = '' ^ in
>   /home/www.site.com/file.php on line 265

What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The scope of the function does not include variables declared outside of it.
Don't use global variables, instead allow the function access by passing $con as a parameter:

```
function _get_product($product_id, $con){
```

And use this to call it:

```
 _get_product($line_value['productId'], $con);
```

Comment: I was typing it before you made the comment in my defense :\

Comment: having done that, I'm still getting this error: `Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" LINE 3: WHERE id = '' ^ in` Is there something meaningful about that ^ just outside the quotes? THanks!

Comment: He had a typo... the function call should be `_get_product($line_value['productId'], $con);`

Comment: @thomas The issue is that you were using the wrong variable to get the id, so it wasn't inserting one into the query. Thanks TheSmose for the edit, which will solve your error.

Comment: @thomas the `^` would probably point to the `''` if it were spaced the way it was supposed to be, to point the error in the query out to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register `$con` as a global variable inside the function (so it's imported, rather than declared new locally).

Make it this:

```
function _get_product($product_id) {
    global $con;
```

Comment: Better to take $con as a parameter of the function, e.g. `function _get_product($product_id, $con)` - it's almost always a bad idea to use globals.